# Can I Retrieve Deleted Content From An Apex Class?

Tags: apex, class

I had an `Apex Class` of 900+ Lines Of Code two days ago. Now it only has 2 LOC. How can I retrieve the missing code? Is it possible to get it back?

Comment: Check out Salesforce documentation : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181984&language=en_US
If the query gives nothing, then you may not be able to recover the class.

Comment: If you did development in Eclipse or like any IDE, you can compare class file with local history.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is: you can't. If it's in a sandbox and you contact salesforce ASAP they *may* have a copy of your sandbox and *may* be able to restore it. I can verify I've had it done.